# Finding IPFS Hash by leading Bits

Tags: ipfs

Is it possible to find **IPFS** hashes by their leading bits? Lets say I have some files and by adding a nonce to each of them I create hashes which all start with the **same n Bits**. Is it possible for a client to find these files by searching for hashes that start with these bits?

If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR: No**

The two main ways IPFS looks for data that is available on the network are:

1. Using a Distributed Hash Table which allows asking peers "do you know who has the data with hash X?"
2. Asking peers you are already connected to "do you have the data with hash X?"

This means that there is no efficient way to ask "do you know who has the data with hash starting with the bits Y?".